# Custom dimensions values passed over, but not available in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

html code:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
            'dimension1': '@useType',
            'dimension2': '@artType'
        });
```

The custom dimensions values are right in google tag assistant.

[image]

In google analytics, i added both the custom dimensions in admin settings page. But I couldn't see the passed over values in google analytics.

Am i missing any configuration?

Kindly help.

Comment: Are you looking in the correct place? Behavior > Site Content > All Pageviews > Secondary Dimension > [My CD]. You should see your data there assuming the CDs are being sent up properly.

Comment: Thank you very much mate. I could see the data now. I was looking at the wrong place :D

Comment: Awesome to hear. You can use custom reports as well, but this is easy to check. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks mate. Cheers! Best of luck :)